# I want to set default value that is missing when click on the dropdown list.I would like to be unable to select "Please select" value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to set default value which will miss when click on the dropdown list.I would like to be unable to select "Please select" value. When I click on "Please select" value in materialId or depotId, "" null value send by ajax and I am getting error. How can I prevent this?

Create.cshtml

```
  <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.materialId, "Material names", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("materialId", null, "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control chosen" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.materialId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.depotId, "Product Outlet", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("depotId", null, "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.depotId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#depotId').change(function () { sendDataByAjax(); });
                $('#materialId').change(function () { sendDataByAjax(); });
        })
    function sendDataByAjax() {
        var materialId= $('#materialId option:selected').val();
        var depotId= $('#depotId option:selected').val();

        if (materialId == "" || depotId == "") {
          // I can not write this
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: {
                'materialId': materialId,
                'depotId': depotId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stock").html(data);
                }
        });
        }
    </script>
}
```

I am getting error here when "" goes to my controller. Because it is not int.

OutgoingProductController.cs

```
public string GetStock(string materialId, string depotId)
{
    int did = int.Parse(depotId);
    int mid = int.Parse(materialId);
```

Comment: What kind of value you've got in `materialId` and `depotId` when the placeholder text item is selected? Are they assigned with `undefined` (use `console.log()` to see them)?

Comment: I am getting numbers from both materialId and depotId like "1050", "3" when I select from lists. But when I select "Please select" value, I am getting null "" value.

Comment: why don't you change your if condition to check for `null` instead of `""`?

Comment: @büşratabak, So what you expect which values would be return when you select "Please select" ?

Comment: Of course, I tried null instead of "". not work

Comment: Is that `null` value propagates to AJAX `data` setting? Also I found typo on `depoId` which should be `depotId`, probably this is reason why your `depotId` value not properly passed to controller action.

Comment: I updated my codes

Comment: Again I found you're using `string depoId` as parameter but your AJAX uses `'depotId': depotId`, should it use `depotId` instead? Difference in naming may causing your AJAX doesn't recognize the parameter in controller action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your dropdownlist selected values are passed as numeric values, you may use `parseInt()` function to try parsing numeric value from client-side and then check against `NaN`, if the value is numeric then trigger AJAX callback:

```
function sendDataByAjax() {
    var materialId = parseInt($('#materialId option:selected').val());
    var depotId = parseInt($('#depotId option:selected').val());

    if (isNaN(materialId) || isNaN(depotId)) {
        // do something, e.g. alert user
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: {
                'materialId': materialId,
                'depotId': depotId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stock").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then make sure that your action method contains `int` type for both parameters, hence no need to use `int.Parse()` which will throwing exception if parsed string has null value:

```
public ActionResult GetStock(int materialId, int depotId)
{
    int did = depotId;
    int mid = materialId;

    // other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `false` when `materialId == "" || depotId == ""` :

```
function sendDataByAjax() {
        var materialId= $('#materialId option:selected').val();
        var depotId= $('#depotId option:selected').val();

        if (materialId == "" || depotId == "") {
          return false;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "@Url.Action("GetStock", "OutgoingProduct")",
            data: {
                'materialId': materialId,
                'depotId': depotId
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#stock").html(data);
                }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the way to solve this is not the way you're trying to do it. the way to do should be to use the validation system, available for MVC.

Change your get method to use a model, something like:

```
public class StockRequestModel
{
    [Required]    
    public int materialId { get; set }

    [Required]
    public int depoId { get;set; }
}
```

Your controller method can then become something like:

```
public string GetStock([FromUri] StockRequestModel model)
{
    if ( !ModelState.IsValid )
    {
         some code here
    } 

    //at this point your model is valid and you have IDs so can proceed with your code
}
```

Normally, in MVC you would return the original View with the state in the result, so you can then trigger the front end validation. In your case, you seem to have a WebAPI controller in an MVC app, but you can still use front end validation.

There are other questions related to yours, such as [Client side validation with Angularjs and Server side validation with Asp.net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39750783/client-side-validation-with-angularjs-and-server-side-validation-with-asp-net-mv)

Normally I'd vote to close it as duplicate, but in this case, I think it's worthwhile pointing out the issue and solution.

Another place to go would be https://angularjs.org/ and then check the Form Validation section for pure front end validation. Of course you'd want to keep both front end and back end validations.